# (Angular + Bootstrap) How to stop two datepickers from being opened by the same button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a web page that needs two datepickers, start date and end date. The problem is, whenever I click on the glyph to open the date selector, both date picker opens at the same time.

Here is my Template, Directive, Controller and how it's being used. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Template**:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" ng-model="start_date" is-open="popup.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Directive**:

```
'use strict';
/*global angular*/

angular.module("myApp")
.directive("datepicker", function(){
    return{
        templateUrl: 'templates/datePicker.html',
        controller: 'newDateCtrl',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
/*global angular*/
angular.module("myApp").controller("newDateCtrl", function($scope) {

    $scope.popup = {
        opened: false
    };

    $scope.open = function() {
        $scope.popup.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
        minDate: new Date(),
        startingDay: 1
    };

})
```

**index.html**, as part of a form like this:

```
....
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
        Start Date
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <datepicker></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">
        End Date
    </label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <datepicker></datepicker>
    </div>
</div>
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:
- when declaring your directive, use an isolate scope.

i.e.

```
.directive('...', function() {
  return {
   .... // your existing stuff
   scope: {} // this gives each directive instance isolated scope
  }
});
```

- I think also 'datepicker' is the name of the bootstrap directive already, so if you're wrapping it you should consider giving it a different name.